# In Vim, why are the navigation keys HJKL and not JKL;?

Tags: vim

How does this not bother anyone? I used to rebind it but recently I've been trying the standard layout just to see what I'm missing. Isn't it easier to not move your finger to H and then back again to J?

And I know VIM has some ancestor(s) that had the same four keys, but that's not really the reason. VIM didn't have to use those keys.

Comment: That is really the reason.

Comment: No. For instance, VIM could have bound these operations to Z, F, Y, and +. It's a very simple question. Is there a technical reason why ";" can't be used, and does it not bother anyone else to move your finger more to go left.

Comment: It doesn't bother me - I use the `;` a lot to repeat the last `f`, `F`, `t` and
`T` command (and its counterpart `,` to repeat them in the opposite direction).
I wouldn't want to use `j` and `,` for these things (which is what would happen
with the `jkl;` scheme...

Comment: What do you mean “no”. That’s literally why the author chose those keys. Who said it was a technical reason? (And as for why vi uses those keys, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vi, specifically <https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vi#/media/File:KB_Terminal_ADM3A.svg>. FWIW, no, it doesn’t bother me.)

Comment: A relevant ref https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/9315

Comment: Links were changed to the followings: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vi_(text_editor)  ,  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vi_(text_editor)#/media/File:KB_Terminal_ADM3A.svg

Answer (score 10):

30 years ago, Vim's author created it because he couldn't run vi on his amiga for licensing reasons. The whole point of the existence of Vim was to provide a convincing vi clone so it uses `hjkl`, just like the original. Vim evolved quite a lot over time but that primary goal didn't go away. If you don't like `hjkl` map them to something that makes more sense to you.

It may come as a shock to you, but Vi's (and thus Vim's) use of `hjkl` for cursor movement **has literally nothing to do with touch-typing *at all***.

For reference:

- Vim uses `hjkl` because vi did.
- Vi used `hjkl` because its creator's keyboard didn't have physical cursor keys. Instead, the arrows were printed on the `hjkl` keys.
- The arrow keys were printed on `hjkl` because the corresponding control codes all moved the cursor in directions roughly similar to the cursor keys: `^H` for "backspace, `^J` for "line feed", `^K` for "upline", and `^L` for "forward space".

Comment: What was the use of hjkl for then? Sorry, I can't upvote :<

Comment: I upvoted because of the sentence in bold. :-) My fingers could never make sense of `hjkl` and I shamelessly use the arrow keys that 21th-century keyboards have (and which, by the way, also work in insert-mode). Yet I believe I’m a fine touch-typer.

Comment: Where's bullet point 4 ??? Please explain the mystery behind why hjkl were chosen for those control codes. Why not jikl for example?

Comment: @minseong see https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/42428/54.